# How to download Leaflet vectors in GPX format?

Tags: vector, leaflet, gpx

I would like to use the leaflet.draw plugin to allow users to digitize vectors on the map. At the end the data should be downloadable as a GPX-file.

Is there any sample that shows how this can be done?

Comment: Do you want a set of waypoints, a route (plan for what to do) or a track (record of what happened)? Do you need time association with these points / vectors?

Answer (score 2):

If processing on the serverside is an option you can consider using ogr2ogr, which supports geojson and gpx.
http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with OpenLayers. You can use `OpenLayers.Format.GPX` to read/write GPX files. Leaflet Supports reading GPX files through plugins but i'm not sure if it supports writing as well.